# Clarity regarding a proof in approximating even functions

Tags: real-analysis, approximation

The question asked in (ISI-JRF) exam was:

> Let $f$ be a real valued continuous function on $[-1,1]$ such that $f(x)=f(-x)\forall x\in[-1,1]$. Show that $\forall\epsilon\gt0,\ \exists$ a polynomial $p(x)$ with rational coeficients such that $\forall x\in[-1,1]$,$$|f(x)-p(x^2)|\le\epsilon$$.

My proof ran as follows:

By the Weierstraß aproximation theorem, we have that every real valued uniformly continuous function can be approximated by a polynomial with real coefficients, i.e. $\forall\epsilon\gt0,\forall x\in[-1,1],\exists q(x)$(polynomial) such that $$|f(x)-q(x)|\lt\epsilon\cdots(1)$$. Also, by the evenness of the given function, we have:-$$|f(-x)-q(-x)|<\epsilon\implies|f(x)-q(-x)|<\epsilon\cdots(2)$$. Now, adding $(1)+(2)$:- $$|f(x)-q(x)|+|f(x)-q(-x)|<2\epsilon$$. Hence, by triangle inequality, $$|q(x)-q(-x)|\lt2\epsilon$$, i.e., the polynomial is also even. Hence, $\exists$ a polynomial $p(x)$ such that $p(x^2)=q(x)$. Now, since rational numbers are dense in real numbers, therefore, we obtain the desired result.

I think the above proof is correct. If the proof is incorrect, please provide hints regarding right proof. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Your choice of $q$ depends on $\epsilon$, so you have only shown that each $q$ is *almost* even, not actually even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that,
as angryavian commented,
$q$ is almost even.

For any function $f$,
$g(x)
=\frac12(f(x)+f(-x))
$
is exactly even.

So,
consider
$r(x)
=\frac12(q(x)+q(-x))
$.
Then
$r(x)$ is exactly even
and
$|r(x)-q(x)|
=|\frac12(q(x)-q(-x))|
$
is also small,
so
$|r(x)-f(x)|$
is also small.

Now use $r(x)$
as a polynomial with
only terms with
even exponents.